# Enable usb0 NIC for initramfs

Tags: boot, networking, kernel, initramfs

I am attempting to USB tether an android phone to a pi.  It appears that when I edit the `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/init` script to insert `IP=:::::usb0:dhcp` that I am unable to get a dhcp lease on the usb0 interface. I thought that perhaps I need to add the rndis_host kernel module, so I edited `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/modules` to add the line `rndis_host` however when I rebuild with `mkinitramfs -o /boot/initrd.img "5.4.0-1042-raspi"` , I do not see any output from `lsinitramfs /boot/initrd.img | grep rndis`

Any suggestions on how I can enable usb0 with DHCP from initramfs? My initramfs works fine if I have enabled Ethernet tethering from the android device, and use eth0 DHCP.

This is an Ubuntu 20.04 Server Pi image.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Thanks for asking - updated question